# Why does PHP not provide an Epsilon constant for floating point comparisons?

Tags: php, floating-point, epsilon

After seeing many PHP questions about comparing the equality of floats where the answer is to simply choose an arbitrary value for Epsilon and then do `if( abs($a-$b) < 0.000001 )`.

The trouble is that Epsilon is typically *much* smaller than the values people tend to choose [2.22e-16 on my machine] and is actually quite simple to calculate:

```
$macheps = (float) 1.0;  
do {
    $macheps /= (float) 2.0;
} while( (float) (1.0 + ($macheps/2.0)) != 1.0 );
printf("Epsilon: %0.25f\n", $macheps);
```

C++ has `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`, Python has `sys.float_info.epsilon`, so why does PHP leave it up in the air?

Comment: Probably because different people will have different requirements for precision

Comment: "the answer is to simply choose an arbitrary value for Epsilon". This answer is simple, appealing, and dead wrong. Don't do that.

Comment: `PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON` was added in PHP 7.2: _Smallest representable positive number x, so that x + 1.0 != 1.0_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++'s `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` was never intended to be used in place of `0.000001` in a formula of the style `abs($a-$b) < 0.000001`. For instance, with most C++ compilation platforms, `fabs(x - 2.5) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` is equivalent to `x ==  2.5`, because `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` is a representation of the `double` definition near `1`.

Some programmers may need to compare floating-point numbers up to some value, but that value has little reason to be related to the definition of the floating-point format near 1, so that's not a good reason to provide that constant in the language. Instead, the value should come either from requirements (“as small as needed”) or by inference (“the floating-point results can be 0.003 from the real result, so `fabs(x - 2.5) < 0.003` will never be false if the real result can be 2.5”).

Answer (score 20):

I know this is an old question, but as of PHP 7.2 it is provided.

`PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON` (float)

Smallest representable positive number x, so that x + 1.0 != 1.0. Available as of PHP 7.2.0.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php